# Is my distributed database C+A or A+P?

Tags: distributed, partition, cap-theorem

Let a distributed database have a recover mechanism such as, in case it is splitted by a network partition which allows two sides to keep working, both sides continue to commit transactions and, when the partition is ending, they agree to go back to the last common state.

Should we say that this system :

- is A+P, as it has a built-in (not very clever) mechanism to deal with partitions, and the consistency is sort of broken by the fact we can deny a commit which has been done ?
- is C+A, as it does not *really* deals with partitions, and the state is always consistent (never a mixed weird thing recorded) ?
- another more complicated option ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. If you have a programming question, please share the code for the program that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when the partition is ending, they agree to go back to the last common state."

Do you mean to say all the writes since time t1 (when partition split occurs) to time t2 (when partition split ends) are lost?

That makes your database neither consistent nor durable.

However, you'd be providing availability and partition tolerance.

Comment: Exactly ! Could we say it's AP ?

Comment: Yes, you would be providing Availability and partition tolerance. I'll update my answer.